# julian dates as.date

Tags: macos, r, linear-regression, julian-date

I am trying to run a simple regression in R (mac OSX), to see if the level of an environmental certification has improved over time - among other things.  The data I downloaded offers a level from 1-4, and the dates in 1-Mar-12 format.  I can't seem to get R to convert the dates, and I keep getting the same error message.  The variables are the same length.

```
$ certification_date: chr  "1-Aug-11" "1-Aug-11" "1-Aug-11" "1-Jul-11" ...

jday<-as.Date('certification_date',format='%d-%b-%y',"%j")
mod <- lm(Level_number ~ jday, data=data)

Error in model.frame.default(formula = Level_number ~ jday, data = data,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'jday')

summary(jday)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     "1"
```

Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong?

Comment: remove the single quotes around `'certification_date'` when calling `as.Date`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the quotes around `certification_date` as mentioned in the comment, But `%b` is the abbreviated month name in the current locale. So you can get another problem with your locals. Here I present a independent-local solution:

```
## get your current local time
loc <- Sys.getlocale('LC_TIME')  
## set the local to english , since %b is local dependent 
Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME','ENGLISH')
jday <-as.Date(certification_date,format='%d-%b-%y',"%j")
Sys.setlocale('LC_TIME',loc)
```

The result is:

```
jday
[1] "2011-08-01" "2011-08-01" "2011-08-01" "2011-07-01"
```